# gcc -o how to name object file

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

This command

```
gcc file.c -c
```

outputs me this

```
file.o
```

how to run above command so it outputs me object file with specified name for example `file.dbg.o` ?

Comment: `-o nameofoutputfile`.

Comment: @EOF I need to run it with -c not -o

Comment: @JoachimPileborg ? I looked it up online without success

Comment: @tomtom  `gcc -c file.c -o file.dbg.o` aight? `-o` does not mean *object* or `.o`, it means *output*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's it:

```
    gcc -o file.dbg.o -c file.c
```

Comment: And if you're under linux/mac type in the terminal `man gcc` to view a list of all the possible options.